# calculating multivariate regression using Statistics::Regression

Tags: perl, statistics, regression

I'd like to use the Perl module of Statistics::Regression for calculating multivariate regression:

[Statistics::Regression](http://search.cpan.org/~iawelch/Statistics-Regression-0.53/Regression.pm)

and for that I was hoping to find an example code that uses this package for this purpose.

Does anyone here know where I can find such code?
(Could not find anything in CPAN...):

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think I somehow managed to work something out from the source code. I could not find/understand where to find the P-value... Any ideas where I might find it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Example_with_real_data Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`plane` in Chemistry::Ring](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Chemistry-Ring/Chemistry/Ring.pm.html#plane-)

Comment: Thanks, it is a good example! You wouldn't happen to know where I can find this elusive P-value by any chance, right?